# Assignment performance in data.frame's constructor

Tags: r, dataframe, microbenchmark

I am having trouble understanding the how `data.frame` construction works.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255046/why-is-it-slower-to-prespecify-type-in-a-data-frame), but I thought that preassigning the columns in a `data.frame` was slow if you wanted to replace data afterwards (duplicated work).

Then I ran the following benchmark, and found that passing the data as arguments to the `data.frame` constructor is way slower than just constructing a `data.frame` and then assigning the data.

What happens here?

```
library(microbenchmark)


# Prep -------------------#

n = 1000
s = seq(n)

f = runif(n)
g = as.factor(sample(1:100, size = n, replace = T))
h = runif(n)
i = sample(LETTERS[1:26], size = n, replace = T)


# Functions --------------#

## Construct data.frame and then assign
f_dollar = function(){
    d = data.frame(row.names  = s,
                   check.rows = F, check.names = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
    d$first  = f
    d$second = g
    d$third  = h
    d$fourth = i
}


## Construct data.frame assigning named vectors
f_named   = function(){
    d = data.frame(first = f, second = g, third = h, fourth = i,
                   check.rows = F, check.names = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
}

## Construct data.frame assigning unnamed vectors
f_unnamed = function(){
    d = data.frame(f, g, h, i,
                   check.rows = F, check.names = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
}


# Profile ----------------#

microbenchmark(f_dollar(), f_named(), f_unnamed())
```

And the results:

```
Unit: microseconds
        expr     min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  f_dollar()  65.808  79.691  92.5668  87.3850 100.6715  191.446   100
   f_named() 205.962 221.761 245.2758 231.8325 251.2915  538.911   100
 f_unnamed() 269.416 283.689 339.8429 297.1045 332.8925 2800.185   100
```

Comment: I agree, your results are pretty non-intuitive at first, but may be a by-product of using such small sets of data.  If you bump your n up to 100000 you should see results consistent with your expectations (at least I do).

Comment: If you look at the code for `data.frame` you may notice that in the case that no data is passed (as in `f_dollar`) it exits very early. My guess would be that `$<-` has less overhead than churning through the rest of the code in `data.frame`, at least for the scale of the data in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `n=100000` and running your `microbenchmark()` for 1000 trials to iron out any variation yields the following:

```
> microbenchmark(f_dollar(), f_named(), f_unnamed(), times=1000)
Unit: microseconds
        expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq      max neval
  f_dollar() 16559.490 17000.361 17444.4909 17282.3785 17587.723 24130.81  1000
   f_named()   211.338   233.266   277.4680   254.2595   302.779  2028.94  1000
 f_unnamed()   260.325   288.783   391.2701   313.7420   366.693 44304.51  1000
```

This would support your initial impression that creating your data.frame object with data included is far more efficient than adding it after the fact which recreates the data.frame at each variable append as far as I know.

Comment: What version of R did you test on?

Comment: 3.1.2, are you seeing vastly different results for different versions of R?